# Is it possible to connect and read multiple serial ports in Raspberry Pi simultaneously?

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, serial-port, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

One Raspberry Pi is connected to two serial devices through USB lines.
One is called **dev/ttyUSB0** and another
one is called **dev/ttyUSB1** by default.
I have two programs running in c#, one reads USB0 and another one USB1. When I run them one after the other, either one stops after 15 seconds but the process stays alive in the background.
How to read both the ports simultaneously by two separate programs?

Comment: What have you already tried? I recommend you read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question

Comment: I tried reading those two separate ports but seems like only one serial port can be read at a time

Comment: Help us help you by posting some code and examples of what you did to try and get it working we can't help you like this. I'm not even sure it's a code problem, might be Linux for all I know

Comment: I don't have any hands on experience with Pi, but to me it is inconceivable that it couldn't access multiple USB devices simultaneously.

Comment: You need to add two `SerialPort` objects to your c# project.  Both of them will have their own `OnDataReceived` events.